# Linear transformation proof validity

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the statement:

Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and $T_1 : V → W$ and $T_2 : V → W$ are linear.
Show that if $u_1, . . . , u_n ∈ V$ spans V and $T_1u_i = T_2u_i$ for all 1 ≤ i ≤ n, then T1 = T2, i.e.,
$T_1x = T_2x$ for all x ∈ V

Proof:
Suppose $\operatorname{Span}\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}=V$
$\exists x \in V\ s.t \ \ x=a_1u_1+ \dots +a_nu_n$
$T_1(x)=T_1(a_1u_1+ \dots +a_nu_n)$
$T_1(x)=a_1T_1u_1+ \dots +a_nT_1u_n$
$T_1(x)=a_1T_2u_1+ \dots +a_nT_2u_n$ by $T_1x = T_2x$
$T_1(x)=T_2(a_1u_1+ \dots +a_nu_n)$
So $T_1(x)=T_1(a_1u_1+ \dots +a_nu_n)=T_2(a_1u_1+ \dots +a_nu_n),$ So $T_1x = T_2x$ for all x in V

I feel like my proof is wrong because of the $T_1(x)=$ part, any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is correct, if you write "by $T_1u_i=T_2u_i$" instead of "by $T_1x=T_2x$"

Comment: It is correct except that the first line should be rephrased: Let $x \in V$. Then $\exists a_1,..,a_n$ such that $x =\sum a_iu_i$.